# ClassCastException while parsing a complex type in a ksoap2 response

Tags: parsing, response, ksoap2

I've been searching a lot of similar topics but none of them work for my case. I know my complex class need to implements KvmSerializable. I also add the class mapping in soap envelope. But there's still ClassCastException. Can anyone please help point out what's wrong with my codes?

The web service signature: CUser CreateRegisteredUser();

WSDL:

```html
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://192.168.5.6/" targetNamespace="http://192.168.5.6/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema targetNamespace="http://192.168.5.6/">
            <s:complexType name="CUser">
                <s:annotation>
                    <s:documentation>
                        User information
                    </s:documentation>
                </s:annotation>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="userToken" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                User token
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="userRole" type="s:int">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                User role
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="userState" type="s:int">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                User state
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="userName" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                User name
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="password" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Password
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="email" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Email
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="mobilePhone" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Mobile phone #
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="expr" type="s:int">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Experience
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="points" type="s:int">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Points
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="registerDate" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Registered date
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="gender" type="s:int">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Gender
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="location" type="s:string">
                        <s:annotation>
                            <s:documentation>
                                Location
                            </s:documentation>
                        </s:annotation>
                    </s:element>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="UserManagerSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:message name="UserManagerSoapOut" />
    <wsdl:message name="CreateAnonymousUserSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:message name="CreateAnonymousUserSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="s:string">
            <s:documentation>
                user token
            </s:documentation>
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="CreateRegisteredUser2SoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="user" type="tns:CUser">
            <s:documentation>
                User information to register
            </s:documentation>
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="CreateRegisteredUser2SoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="tns:CUser">
            <s:documentation>
                User information registered. Null indicates failures
            </s:documentation>
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="CreateRegisteredUserSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:message name="CreateRegisteredUserSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="tns:CUser">
            <s:documentation>
                User information registered. Null indicates failures
            </s:documentation>
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateAnonymousUserSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="user_token" type="s:string">
            <s:documentation>
                user token
            </s:documentation>
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateAnonymousUserSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="s:boolean">
            <s:documentation>
                result
            </s:documentation>
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="UserManagerSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="UserManager">
            <wsdl:documentation>
                Constructor
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:UserManagerSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:UserManagerSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateAnonymousUser">
            <wsdl:documentation>
                CreateAnonymousUser
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateAnonymousUserSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateAnonymousUserSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegisteredUser2">
            <wsdl:documentation>
                CreateRegisteredUser2
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateRegisteredUser2SoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateRegisteredUser2SoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegisteredUser">
            <wsdl:documentation>
                CreateRegisteredUser
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateRegisteredUserSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateRegisteredUserSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ValidateAnonymousUser">
            <wsdl:documentation>
                ValidateAnonymousUser
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ValidateAnonymousUserSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ValidateAnonymousUserSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="UserManagerSoap" type="tns:UserManagerSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
        <wsdl:operation name="UserManager">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.5.6/UserManager" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateAnonymousUser">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.5.6/CreateAnonymousUser" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" parts="return" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegisteredUser2">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.5.6/CreateRegisteredUser2" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" parts="user" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" parts="return" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateRegisteredUser">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.5.6/CreateRegisteredUser" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" parts="return" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ValidateAnonymousUser">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.5.6/ValidateAnonymousUser" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" parts="user_token" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.5.6/" parts="return" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="UserManager">
        <wsdl:port name="UserManagerSoap" binding="tns:UserManagerSoap">
            <soap:address location="https://192.168.5.6/user_service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The ksoap2 response. :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://192.168.5.6/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
  <env:Body xmlns:rpc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc">
    <ns1:CreateRegisteredUserResponse env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
      <rpc:result>return</rpc:result>
      <return xsi:type="ns1:CUser">
        <userToken xsi:type="xsd:string">token</userToken>
        <userRole xsi:type="xsd:int">1</userRole>
        <userState xsi:type="xsd:int">2</userState>
        <userName xsi:type="xsd:string">aaa</userName>
        <password xsi:type="xsd:string">123456</password>
        <email xsi:type="xsd:string">aaa@aaa.com</email>
        <mobilePhone xsi:type="xsd:string">15201193843</mobilePhone>
        <expr xsi:type="xsd:int">0</expr>
        <points xsi:type="xsd:int">0</points>
        <registerDate xsi:type="xsd:string">registerDate</registerDate>
        <gender xsi:type="xsd:int">0</gender>
        <location xsi:type="xsd:string">location</location>
      </return>
    </ns1:CreateRegisteredUserResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

My CUser class:

```js
public class CUser implements Serializable, KvmSerializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4000559522164150752L;
protected UUID userToken;
protected UserRole userRole;
protected UserState userState;
protected String userName;
protected String password;
protected String email;
protected String mobilePhone;
protected int expr;
protected int points;
protected String registerDate;
protected UserGender gender;
protected String location;

public CUser () {
 this.userRole = UserRole.Unknown;
 this.userState = UserState.Unknown;
 this.gender = UserGender.Unknown;
 this.expr = this.points = 0;
}

public CUser (UUID token) {
 this.userToken = token;
 this.userRole = UserRole.Anonymous;
 this.userState = UserState.Unknown;
 this.gender = UserGender.Unknown;
 this.expr = this.points = 0;
}

public CUser (String name, String password) {
 this.userName = name;
 this.password = password;
 this.userRole = UserRole.Unknown;
 this.userState = UserState.Unknown;
 this.gender = UserGender.Unknown;
 this.expr = this.points = 0;
}

public CUser (
  UUID token, 
  UserRole role, 
  UserState state, 
  String name, 
  String password, 
  String email, 
  String phoneNumber, 
  int expr,
  int points,
  String registerDate,
  UserGender gender) {
 this.userToken = token;
 this.userRole = role;
 this.userState = state;
 this.userName = name;
 this.password = password;
 this.email = email;
 this.mobilePhone = phoneNumber;
 this.expr = expr;
 this.points = points;
 this.registerDate = registerDate;
 this.gender = gender;
}

public UUID getToken() {return this.userToken;}
public UserRole getRole() {return this.userRole;}
public UserState getState() {return this.userState;}
public String getName() {return this.userName;}
public String getPassword() {return this.password;}
public String getEmail() {return this.email;}
public String getPhoneNumber() {return this.mobilePhone;}
public int getExperience() {return this.expr;}
public int getPoints() {return this.points;}
public String getRegisterDate() {return this.registerDate;}
public UserGender getGender() {return this.gender;}

public void setName(String name) {this.userName = name;}
public void setGender(UserGender gender) {this.gender = gender;}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
 // default serialization
 oos.defaultWriteObject();

 oos.writeObject(this.userToken);
 oos.write(this.userRole.getValue());
 oos.writeUTF(this.userName == null ? "" : this.userName);
 oos.writeUTF(this.password == null ? "" : this.password);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
 // default deserialization
 ois.defaultReadObject();
 
 this.userToken = (UUID) ois.readObject();
 this.userRole = UserRole.fromInt(ois.readInt());
 
 try {
  this.userName = ois.readUTF();
  this.password = ois.readUTF();
 } catch (EOFException e) {
  this.userName = null;
  this.password = null;
 }
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
 switch (arg0) {
 case 0:
  return this.userToken == null ? null : this.userToken.toString();
 case 1:
  return this.userRole.getValue();
 case 2:
  return this.userState.getValue();
 case 3:
  return this.userName;
 case 4:
  return this.password;
 case 5:
  return this.email;
 case 6:
  return this.mobilePhone;
 case 7:
  return this.expr;
 case 8:
  return this.points;
 case 9:
  return this.registerDate;
 case 10:
  return this.gender.getValue();
 case 11:
  return this.location;
 }
 return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
 return 12;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
 switch (arg0) {
 case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "userToken";
        break;
 case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "userRole";
        break;
 case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "userState";
        break;
 case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "userName";
        break;
 case 4:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "password";
        break;
 case 5:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "email";
        break;
 case 6:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "mobilePhone";
        break;
 case 7:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "expr";
        break;
 case 8:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "points";
        break;
 case 9:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "registerDate";
        break;
 case 10:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "gender";
        break;
 case 11:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "location";
        break;
 }  
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object value) {
 switch (arg0) {
 case 0:
  this.userToken = UUID.fromString(value.toString());
  break;
 case 1:
  this.userRole = UserRole.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
  break;
 case 2:
  this.userState = UserState.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
  break;
 case 3:
  this.userName = value.toString();
  break;
 case 4:
  this.password = value.toString();
  break;
 case 5:
  this.email = value.toString();
  break;
 case 6:
  this.mobilePhone = value.toString();
  break;
 case 7:
  this.expr = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
  break;
 case 8:
  this.points = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
  break;
 case 9:
  this.registerDate = value.toString();
  break;
 case 10:
  this.gender = UserGender.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
  break;
 case 11:
  this.location = value.toString();
  break;
 }  
}
}
```

The codes to invoke web service:

```js
 public CUser CreateRegisteredUser(String userName, String password, String email, UserGender gender) throws SoapFault, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  String METHOD_NAME = "CreateRegisteredUser";
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
  CUser user = new CUser(
    currentUserToken, 
    UserRole.Registered, 
    UserState.Inactive, 
    userName, 
    password,
    email,
    null,
    0,
    0,
    null, 
    gender);
        
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "CUser", new CUser().getClass());
        
        Object soapResult = InvokeSoapMethed(request, envelope);

        if (soapResult == null) {
         Log.v("UserManagerSoapClient.CreateRegisteredUser", "null");
         return null;
        } else {
         SoapObject soapObj = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
         user = (CUser) soapObj.getProperty(1); // java.lang.ClassCastException
      return null;
        } 
 }


 
 protected Object InvokeSoapMethed(SoapObject request, SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope) throws SoapFault, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  final String SOAP_ACTION = this.NAMESPACE + request.getName();    
  Log.v("Ksoap2WSBase.InvokeSoapMethed", "SOAP_ACTION: " + SOAP_ACTION);

        SoapAsyncTask task = null;
        Object result = null;
        if (envelope == null) {
         envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        }
        
  task = new SoapAsyncTask(this.CreateTransport());
  task.execute(envelope, SOAP_ACTION);

       result = task.get();
  if (result instanceof SoapFault) {
   throw (SoapFault) result;
  }
  
        if (result == null) {
   Log.v("Ksoap2WSBase.InvokeSoapMethed", "Null soap result returned");
         return null;
        }

        DumpSoapResult((SoapObject) result);
  return result; 
 }

public class SoapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {

 protected Transport androidTransport;
 
 public SoapAsyncTask(Transport androidTransport) {
  this.androidTransport = androidTransport;
 }
 
 @Override
 // args[0] = (SoapSerializationEnvelope) envelope
 // args[1] = (String) soap_action
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
  Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", String.format("SoapAction: %s", args[1]));
  
  Object result = null;
        
  try {
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = (SoapSerializationEnvelope) args[0];
   androidTransport.call((String)args[1], envelope);
   result = envelope.bodyIn;
   
   Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", "Dump Request:" + androidTransport.requestDump);
   Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", "Dump Response:" + androidTransport.responseDump);
  } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
   Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", "HttpResponseException");
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", "IOException");
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
   Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", "XmlPullParserException");
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.v("SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground", "Exception");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  return result;
 }

}
```

The logs:

```html
Propert[0]: return

Propert[1]: CUser{userToken=token; userRole=1; userState=2; userName=aaa; password=123456; email=aaa@aaa.com; mobilePhone=15201193843; expr=0; points=0; registerDate=registerDate; gender=0; location=location; }
```